# Cannot drag-reorder tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, tabs, drag-and-drop, windows-11-v23h2

This is driving me absolutely crazy. In recent versions of Chrome, I’ve been unable to drag-reorder tabs consistently. I’m currently running the latest version of Chrome as of today, 120.0.6099.71 (64-bit), on Windows 11 Pro (version 23H2, build 22631.2792).

If I click and drag on a tab, it behaves as if I’ve released the mouse button after a split second, even though I haven’t. So, if I click and drag a tab a short distance to the left or right, it will follow the mouse cursor for a few pixels and then snap back into its original position while I’m still holding down the mouse button. However, if I click and drag very quickly, I *can* move the dragged tab into a new position in the tab bar before the mouse button “releases.”

Even weirder, I’ve discovered that this behavior only occurs when clicking and dragging on the *top half* of a tab (on or above the text label). If I click and drag on the bottom half of a tab, I can drag-reorder it like normal, at any speed.

I’ve tried all the typical generic troubleshooting steps to no avail: uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome, resetting settings, disabling extensions, etc. The behavior occurs in both regular and incognito windows, and with both my laptop’s trackpad and an external mouse.

I cannot find anything online about this *specific* problem in the way I’ve described above, where the behavior only occurs when clicking and dragging on the top half of a tab but not the bottom. I’ve even wondered if this is perhaps a feature of Chrome to help prevent drag-reordering tabs by accident, but I can’t find any documentation stating that this is the intentional behavior, or any way to disable it if so.

Surely I’m not the only person experiencing this, right? Right?!

Comment: Pinning tabs prevents moving them, but surely you tested with more tabs and you're not autopinning all of them somehow?

Comment: No, I’m not pinning them. I _can_ move them if I do it quick enough. It’s as if there’s a timer on the mouse button, and I have to complete the drag within that amount of time or it cancels the operation. And again, it only behaves this way when dragging from the top half of the tab, not the bottom.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: (1) Try to disable (switch off/disable) alternatively the trackpad and the mouse. It cold be that it is sending faulty signals.  (2) [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/m30pq2/cant_move_tabs_fixed/) suggests a peripheral sending interfering signals, so try to disconnect any peripherals and see if the issue persists

Comment: @daGUY: Please answer the comments.